# How do I stop my iPhone messages from appearing on my Mac?

Tags: iphone, messages

We have multiple iPhone and Mac products, but I need to correct one specific problem.  I only use Messages on my iPhone; but for some reason when I am near one of our Macs with my iPhone, my notification sounds for messages incoming to my phone do not play and the messages are appearing on my Mac.  If I delete the messages app from my Mac, will it screw things up on my messages in general?

Answer (score 1):

No. Opting out of message delivery on one device (Mac or iPad) doesn't change delivery to the iPhone.

- Go ahead and disable handoff if you don't want that enabled.
- go ahead and sign out of messages on the Mac if you don't want that enabled.